# Ajax form submit in Ruby on Rails returns 400 Bad Request

Tags: jquery, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, coffeescript

I have a form that I want to submit using Ajax. And now I'm getting an error status 400 Bad Request.

The form is:

```
<%= form_tag client_contacts_path, role: 'form', id: 'nested_client_contact_form', remote: true, method: 'post' do |f| %>
```

And I have ajax call on form submit:

```
$('#nested_client_contact_form').submit ->
  valuesToSubmit = $(this).serialize()
  $.ajax(
    type: 'POST'
    url: '/client_contacts      ',
    contentType: 'application/json'
    data: valuesToSubmit
    dataType: 'json').success (json) ->
    # some code
    return
  false
```

This should create new client contact and remain on the page. No redirection.

Comment: If you use `remote: true`, you don't need to write those js code. Just make sure your view folder has `your_action_name.js` file. And your action do respond to js

Comment: I've changed indentation like it is in the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end it worked by using just remote: true without CoffeeScript